# Docker java api maven Build error: busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first

Tags: maven, docker, java, dockerhub

I am trying to build the [Java API for docker](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) by cloning it from its git repository and then building using maven as follows:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=false -Ddocker.io.username=username -Ddocker.io.password=password -Ddocker.io.email=my@email.id
```

However, the build test fails resulting in the following error message:

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  testRunShlex(com.github.dockerjava.client.DockerClientTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testAuth(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.AuthCmdTest): com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 404
  testAuthInvalid(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.AuthCmdTest): expected:<401> but was:<404>
  testAddAndCopySubstitution(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  testDockerBuilderAddFileInSubfolder(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  testDockerBuilderAddFolder(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  testDockerBuilderAddUrl(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  testNetCatDockerfileBuilder(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  testNginxDockerfileBuilder(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.BuildImageCmdTest): 
  commit(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.CommitCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testDiff(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.ContainerDiffCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  copyFromContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.CopyFileFromContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  createContainerWithEnv(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.CreateContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  createContainerWithHostname(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.CreateContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  createContainerWithVolume(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.CreateContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  info(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.InfoCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testKillContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.KillContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testListContainers(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.ListContainersCmdTest): Client response status: 404
  listImages(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.ListImagesCmdTest)
  logContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.LogContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testPullImage(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.PullImageCmdTest): com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 404
  testNotExistentImage(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.PushImageCmdTest): 
  testPushLatest(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.PushImageCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  removeContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.RemoveContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testRemoveImage(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.RemoveImageCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  restartContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.RestartContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  searchImages(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.SearchImagesCmdTest): com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 404
  startContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.StartContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  startContainerWithLinking(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.StartContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  startContainerWithPortBindings(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.StartContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  startContainerWithVolumes(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.StartContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testStopContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.StopContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.
  testTagImage(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.TagImageCmdTest): 
  version(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.VersionCmdTest): com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 404
  testWaitContainer(com.github.dockerjava.client.command.WaitContainerCmdTest): busybox is an unrecognized image. Please pull the image first.

Tests run: 35, Failures: 35, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
```

Pasted the complete output [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8088782/).

I tried pulling busybox image from docker hub using:

```
sudo docker pull busybox
```

and it results in the following message:

```
Pulling repository busybox
fd5373b3d938: Download complete 
d200959a3e91: Download complete 
37fca75d01ff: Download complete 
a9eb17255234: Download complete 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
42eed7f1bf2a: Download complete 
120e218dd395: Download complete 
f06b02872d52: Download complete 
c120b7cab0b0: Download complete 
1f5049b3536e: Download complete
```

which I assume successfully downloads busybox image. However, trying to rebuild the Java API results in the same error message.

How can I resolve this and build the Java API successfully?

---

**System specifications:**

Host machine: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS

The output of `sudo docker version`:

```
Client version: 0.9.1
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 3600720
Server version: 0.9.1
Git commit (server): 3600720
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Last stable version: 1.1.2, please update docker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java API is configured to run using Docker 1.1, try updating Docker.

> Java API client for Docker
>
> Supports a subset of the Docker Client API v1.13, Docker Server version 1.1
>
> Developer forum for docker-java

Check the instruction on the official site : https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-trusty-1404-lts-64-bit

Make sure you have openjdk for development.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Then change your JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`

You are using the JRE which is not made for that purpose and seem to be buggy.

Comment: Trying upgrading, will revert back as soon its completed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Upgraded using the instruction the link you provided gave, but still the error message remains the same. However the output of `sudo docker version` is now: `Client version: 1.1.2
Client API version: 1.13
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): d84a070
Server version: 1.1.2
Server API version: 1.13
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): d84a070
`

Comment: @i08in I cloned the git repo. And built it without any problem. Does your JAVA_HOME environment variable is correctly configured ? Does your maven and java files are up to date?

Comment: yes `JAVA_HOME` has been set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/` and maven version is `Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
Java version: 1.7.0_55
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.13.0-34-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"` java is `java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)` and javac version is `javac 1.7.0_55`.

Comment: I found that I had maven 2 installed, upgraded it to 3.0.5, but the error still remains. I also observe that there is a warning that comes up early in the output: `[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details`.

Comment: Thanks Regan! I had to pull up some jars manually since it was complaining about invalid POM and also as you said, I changed the `JAVA_HOME` variable and restarted the system (instead of just logging in back) and voila, its working! Thanks! :)